# tail pipe grep pipe xmllint not working

Tags: grep, pipe, tail, xmllint

I'm trying to get the below command working but no o/p is getting printed:

```bsh
tail -f mylog.log | grep --line-buffered -Eo '<S:Envelope .+Envelope>' | xmllint --format --recover -
```

However, if I grep the same pattern from a file, and pipe it to xmllint, it works:

```bsh
grep --line-buffered -Eo '<S:Envelope .+Envelope>' tmp.xml | xmllint --format --recover -
```

What am I missing in the first command?

Comment: Maybe `xmllint` tries to read until EOF? In the case of a pipe, it doesn't see any

Comment: Isn't `grep` the culprit here?

Comment: I guess it has more to do with what @fge mentioned. xmllint probably isn't able to find EOF. But is there a way for this to work?

Comment: I'm wondering what the `-` at the end of the command means. Could someone explain or say what it's called so I can google that? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try this (untested):

```
tail -f mylog.log | grep -Eo '<S:Envelope .+Envelope>' | while read line; do
    echo $line | xmllint --format --recover -
done
```

(that is under the hypothesis that `xmllint` does not find EOF and as such is still waiting for input)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
grep --line-buffered -Eo '<S:Envelope .+Envelope>' <(tail -f mylog.log) &1> xmllint --format --recover -
```

Comment: Didn't work. It throws this error: `bash: --format: command not found`